# Splunk: Return One or True from a search, use that result in another search

Tags: splunk

In Splunk, I am looking for logs that say "started with profile: [profile name]" and retrieve the profile name from found events. Then I want to use the profile name to look for other events (from a different source) and if one error or more are found, I would like to let it count as one found error, per platform.

To make things more clear I have the following search query (**query one**):

```
index="myIndex" "started with profile" BD_L*
| table _raw, platform, RUNID
| eval Platform=case(searchmatch("LINUX"),"LINUX",searchmatch("AIX"),"AIX",searchmatch("DB2"),"DB2", searchmatch("SQL"),"SQL", searchmatch("WEBSPHERE"),"WEBSPHERE", searchmatch("SYBASE"),"SYBASE", searchmatch("WINDOWS"),"WINDOWS", true(),"ZLINUX") 
| stats count by Platform
| rename count AS "Amount"
```

The events found from above query contains the following (raw) :

```
Discovery run, 2021101306351355 started with profile BD_L2_Windows
```

The above query will return a list of events containing the raw data above and will result in the following table. This is a table with the amount of Discovery runs per platform:

[image]

Using the following piece of code I can extract RUNID from the events. RUNID is what I need to use in a second search when looking for errors:

```
| rex "Discovery run, (?<RUNID>.+) started with profile"
```

Using RUNID I can look for errors (**query two**):

```
index="myIndex" source="/*/RUNID/*" CASE("ERROR") CTJT* 
| dedup _raw   
| stats  count
| rename count AS "Amount"
```

Now, I am looking for a way to combine the above two queries into one and count the amount of platforms that have at least one error. So lets say we have the following simulation:

- Two runs (one Windows and one Linux)
- Windows run has 0 errors (none found in query 2)
- Linux has 6 errors (found in query 2)

This should result in the following results:

```
Platform     |     Amount
Linux        |          1
```

I need to find some way to return **true** or maybe **one** from query 2 and use that in query 1 to group the results, but I am unable to due to lack of experience. I have not yet found anything similair to my question and hope anyone here can help me out.

So far I can think of the following but this still shows me the same results as in the table shown above (counts of discovery runs per platform instead of counts of platforms that have at least one error):

```
index="myIndex" "started with profile" BD_L* 
| table _raw, platform, RUNID 
| eval Platform=case(searchmatch("LINUX"),"LINUX",searchmatch("AIX"),"AIX",searchmatch("DB2"),"DB2", searchmatch("SQL"),"SQL", searchmatch("WEBSPHERE"),"WEBSPHERE", searchmatch("SYBASE"),"SYBASE", searchmatch("WINDOWS"),"WINDOWS", true(),"ZLINUX") 
| join type=left RUNID
    [ search index="myIndex" source="/*/RUNID/*" CASE("ERROR") CTJT*
        | dedup _raw
        | stats count 
    ]
| stats count by Platform
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

As per request, data samples:

Query 1:

```
2021-10-25 22:01:10,065 ProcessFlowManager [RMI TCP Connection(20)-127.0.0.1]  INFO processflowmgr.ProcessFlowManagerImpl - Discovery run, 2021102522011000 started with profile BD_L2_Windows
```

Query 2:

```
2021-10-25 22:02:11,537 DiscoverManager [DiscoverWorker-47] 2021102522011000#SessionSensor-XX.XXX.XXX.XX-[135,445] ERROR cdb.TivoliStdMsgLogger - CTJTD3028E Sensor SessionSensor encountered an error, Seed: XX.XXX.XXX.XX:[135, 445], Run ID: 2021102522011000.
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have tried the latest answer and got the following result:

[image]

Where as I am expecting a list of Platforms and the amount of errors that are related to the platform. Something like:

```
Platform | Amount (of errors)
zLinux | 2
Windows | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with the help of a colleague:

```
index="myIndex" "started with profile" BD_L* 
| eval platform=case(searchmatch("LINUX"),"LINUX",searchmatch("AIX"),"AIX",searchmatch("DB2"),"DB2", searchmatch("SQL"),"SQL", searchmatch("WEBSPHERE"),"WEBSPHERE", searchmatch("SYBASE"),"SYBASE", searchmatch("WINDOWS"),"WINDOWS", true(),"ZLINUX")
| rex "Discovery run, (?<RUNID>.+) started with profile"
| stats count by platform, RUNID
| join RUNID 
    [ search index="myIndex" source="/opt/XXX/XXXXX/XXXX/log/sensors/*/*" CASE("ERROR") CTJT* 
    | rex field=source "^/opt/XXX/XXXXX/XXXX/log/sensors/(?<RUNID>.+)/" 
    | stats count by RUNID ] 
| stats count by platform
```

Answer (score 2):

First ... don't [`dedup`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/dedup) on `_raw`

The `_raw` events are *never* duplicated (unless you've done something wrong on ingest)

Second, to your actual question - try something along the lines of this:

```
index="myIndex" "started with profile" BD_L* 
| eval Platform=case(match(_raw,"LINUX"),"LINUX",match(_raw,"AIX"),"AIX",match(_raw,"DB2"),"DB2", match(_raw,"SQL"),"SQL", match(_raw,"WEBSPHERE"),"WEBSPHERE", match(_raw,"SYBASE"),"SYBASE", match(_raw,"WINDOWS"),"WINDOWS", true(),"ZLINUX") 
| stats count by Platform RUNID
| join type=left RUNID
    [ search index="myIndex" source="/*/RUNID/*" CASE("ERROR") CTJT*
        | stats count by RUNID
    ]
| stats count by Platform
```

If you can provide some sample data from your two indices, we can get you *much* closer to a good solution - but this should move you towards an answer

There's *likely* a way to *not* use [`join`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/join) in this search - but we need sample data to verify that :)

### EDIT for sample data

This should give you a way to not use `join`, and get what you're looking for:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| rex field=_raw " (?<runid>\d{10,})[\s\#]"
| rex field=_raw "BD_\w+_(?<platform>\w+)"
| rex field=_raw "(?<error>[eEoOrR]{5})"
| stats values(error) as error values(platform) as platform by runid
| where isnotnull(error)
```

*Presuming `platform` always shows up in the format of `BD_<string>_<platform>`*, this will pull the `runid`, `platform`, and `error` (if any) from events, then group them through the `values()` [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) function

Lastly, the [`where`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/where) clause will make sure to only show results wherein an `error` occurred for the given `runid`

### EDIT 2 - OP updated question further: add a `| stats count by platform`:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| rex field=_raw " (?<runid>\d{10,})[\s\#]"
| rex field=_raw "BD_\w+_(?<platform>\w+)"
| rex field=_raw "(?<error>[eEoOrR]{5})"
| stats values(error) as error values(platform) as platform by runid
| where isnotnull(error)
| stats count by platform
```

Comment: The OP mentioned extracting RUNID from the events.  If that is still needed then it should be done on both sides of the `join`.  It can't be extracted and then "passed in" to the subsearch.

Comment: I have added two data samples. They are from the same index. Above code doesn't return any statistics. Only returns events that query 1 returns.

Comment: @RichG: I started with what was originally supplied :)

Comment: @NiekJonkman - see update

Comment: @warren : See my latest update

Comment: I also should have mentioned, query 1 does not fetch from the same source as in query 2.

Comment: @NiekJonkman - see edit2

Comment: Hi @warren, thanks for your help so far, but I am going to stick to the answer I posted. Your query returns 1345710 events in the last 24 hours (on the index and sourcetype). The query my colleague helped me with returns 222 events in the last 24 hours. Also does the query show aditional counts (errors) that correspond with the amout of discovery runs. So for 50 scans started 50 errors show up, while 0 actual errors are logged. Thanks for the help though :) !

Comment: @NiekJonkman - sounds like we can tune this down ... but if you want to stick with your `join`-based answer, cool :)